# scraper got killed automatically on server after few hours, while other spiders keep running on same server

Tags: python, scrapy

I have many scrapers running on  server, one of them got killed after few hours I couldn't understand the reason. while other scrapers keep running at that time.

I have tried options to decrease concurrent requests, but it didn't work

here are my logs

```
2019-06-15 09:57:06,922 - logstats - scrapy.extensions.logstats - INFO - Crawled 10868 pages (at 9 pages/min), scraped 6318 items (at 9 items/min)
2019-06-15 09:58:06,922 - logstats - scrapy.extensions.logstats - INFO - Crawled 10879 pages (at 11 pages/min), scraped 6329 items (at 11 items/min)
2019-06-15 09:59:06,922 - logstats - scrapy.extensions.logstats - INFO - Crawled 10889 pages (at 10 pages/min), scraped 6339 items (at 10 items/min)
2019-06-15 10:00:06,922 - logstats - scrapy.extensions.logstats - INFO - Crawled 10899 pages (at 10 pages/min), scraped 6349 items (at 10 items/min)
Killed
```

Comment: May it be a memory issue? Please, see https://docs.scrapy.org/en/1.6/topics/leaks.html

Comment: If it is a memory issue, other scrapers should also be affected, why only a specific one, everytime

Comment: Maybe there is a per-process memory limit. In any case, please follow the approach suggested in the provided link to debug your issue. At the very least you’ll be able to check that it’s not a memory issue but something else.